# Combine DataGrid filter string from CheckBoxes and TextBoxes WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 2 CheckBoxes and 4 TextBoxes in my application. I am trying to build filter string based on these 6 parameters.

Here is my current code:

```
   // Binding checkbox FIANDSE Bool
    private bool _FIANDSEBool;
    public bool FIANDSEBool
    {
        get => this._FIANDSEBool;
        set
        {
            this._FIANDSEBool = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            // Refresh the DataTable filter expression
            EnableRowFiltering();
        }
    }

    // Binding checkbox ACTIVE Bool
    private bool _ACTIVEBool;
    public bool ACTIVEBool
    {
        get => this._ACTIVEBool;
        set
        {
            this._ACTIVEBool = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            // Refresh the DataTable filter expression
            EnableRowFiltering();
        }
    }

    public void EnableRowFiltering()
    {
        try
        {
            string FIANDSEBoolquery = FIANDSEBool ? " AND YRNRO LIKE '6*' OR YRNRO LIKE '7*'" : "";
            string ACTIVEBoolquery = ACTIVEBool ? " AND KAYTOSSA='1'" : "";

            this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter =
              $"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*'" +
              $"AND HAKUNIMI LIKE '{this.HAKUNIMISearchKey}*'" +
              $"AND KONSERNI LIKE '{this.GROUPSearchKey}*'" +
              $"AND LY LIKE '{this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey}*'" +
              FIANDSEBoolquery + ACTIVEBoolquery;

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {

            // Do nothing
        }
    }
```

It looks like `string ACTIVEBoolquery = ACTIVEBool ? " AND KAYTOSSA='1'" : "";` is working fine, but string `FIANDSEBoolquery = FIANDSEBool ? " AND YRNRO LIKE '6*' OR YRNRO LIKE '7*'" : "";` is probably somehow overriding with `$"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*'"`?

Currently if I apply `FIANDSEBoolquery` and input some text to other TextBoxes, my filter does not work = query is messed up?. However if I apply `ACTIVEBoolquery` and deactivate `FIANDSEBoolquery`, everything seems to be working fine.

Intention of CheckBox `string ACTIVEBoolquery = ACTIVEBool ? " AND KAYTOSSA='1'" : "";` is to filter out all unnecessary rows with values starting with 1, 5, 9 etc. and leave only starting with 6 and 7. Intention of `TextBox $"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*'"` is to filter out more precise if user inputs for example 74003 or 63243 etc.

Any suggestions how get this working?

---

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: What's the exact value of `this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter` when you debug it? And what's the value of `this.YRNROSearchKey`? Maybe you need parentheses around the expression in `FIANDSEBoolquery`: `" AND (YRNRO LIKE '6*' OR YRNRO LIKE '7*') "`

Comment: @mm8 do you mean this (see edited question)?

Comment: Yes, but you need to step over the line where the property is set to be able to see the value, i.e. set the breakpoint of the next line.

Comment: @mm8 thank you for the tip! Now I have managed to 1) Click on Checkbox 2) Step Over couple of times 3) Load data to datagrid. So now there is a string when "Load Data" is pressed with CheckBox active

Comment: @mm8 brackets where missing as you suggested =)) but how is that? Should I delete this question or you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some parentheses around the expression in `FIANDSEBoolquery`:

```
string FIANDSEBoolquery = FIANDSEBool ? " AND (YRNRO LIKE '6*' OR YRNRO LIKE '7*') " 
    : string.Empty;
```